# Prolonging asp.net session enddate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

How is asp.net Session prolonging, **does every request prolongs the end date of Session**, and is it enough to call void() by ajax to extent Session end date by another period of time(default 20 min or so...)

```
public void ResetSessionTime()
{

}
```

or do i have to invoke session in some way:

```
public void ResetSessionTime()
{
    User currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Session[userSessionKey] as User;
}
```

how does simple request extend session end date?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886551/extend-session-time-on-button-click-event-server-side) question claims every post-back prolongs session...

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx) MSDN about Session State Providers :

> "Each session created by ASP.NET has a timeout value (by default, 20
>   minutes) associated with it. If no accesses to the session occur
>   within the session timeout, the session is deemed to be expired, and
>   it is no longer valid."

How does request access the session exactly?

THIS QUESTION: [Keeping session alive C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881768/keeping-session-alive-c-sharp) does not answer how session end date is prolonged by request, only a opinion on how to keep session alive from client side

**EDIT:**

According to [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453), method needs to be extended from IHttpHandler, in order to access current session...

```
public class KeepSessionAlive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["KeepSessionAlive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping session alive C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881768/keeping-session-alive-c-sharp)

Comment: there is no explanation on how session time is prolonged, only that you need to keep page alive, i know you have to make a request, my question is how request prolongs the session, please remove close flag, tnx

Comment: On client start the server sends a cookie, the browser sends it back with each subsequent request. Everytime the server sees that cookie again, it renews it for another X minutes.  All this happens inside of framework code. I'm pretty sure to keep the session alive you just need an additional request before the time out period, that request doesn't need to actually do anything with the session. To know for sure, you'd have to track down the source for the Session classes (and the supporting classes) either via the MS Reference source code or in Mono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you make a request, the session timeout is reset. A request can be a page load or something like an ASYNC call.

Take a look at this question for an example of how to keep the session alive by periodically making AJAX calls to the server. ([Keeping ASP.NET Session Open / Alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive))

Comment: That does not answer actual question. In that answer, there is a line: `context.Session["Heartbeat"] = DateTime.Now;` and actual question asks if that (or similar) line required or it is enough to call empty method.

Comment: I do not believe it is required at all

Comment: P.S. for owin, See also:  CookieAuthenticationProvider -> SlidingExpiration